# Publishing checkins on facebook through android app

Tags: facebook

I've been trying to search for a method which will let me publish checkin details from my third party android app. There is a permission called publish_checkins present in the extended permissions of Facebook, however, I haven't found a specific method that need to be mentioned in order to do this activity. Could anyone please help me out on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the request method provided by the Facebook class with 'POST' as httpMethod. You want to do something like this:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("place", placeid);
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
jo.put("latitude", latitude); 
jo.put("longitude", longitude);
params.putString("coordinates", jo.toString());
facebook.request("me/checkins", params, "POST");
```

More information on checkins can be found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/).

Cheers, Don