# Facebook Checkin from Android App

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to perform a Facebook Checkin from an Android app that I am developing. I know we have to use the graph API. But I am not sure what all are required to get it working. Is there an example code for this?

I reviewed this link: [Publishing checkins on facebook through android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181892/publishing-checkins-on-facebook-through-android-app)

How do I use this code? Any help on this is appreciated.

```
public class FBCheckin extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

Button checkin;

public String pageID;
String FACEBOOK_LINK = "https://www.facebook.com/pizzaguydelivery";

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    final View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fblogin, container, false);
    checkin.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootview;
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(getActivity(), Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
    pageID = FACEBOOK_LINK.substring(FACEBOOK_LINK.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, FACEBOOK_LINK.length());
    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/" + pageID, null, HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                /* handle the result */

            try {
                if (response.getError() == null) {
                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject();
                    if (obj.has("id")) {
                        pageID = obj.getString("id");

                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                        params.putString("message", "Eating");
                        params.putString("place", pageID);
                        // params.putString("link", "URL");

                        if (pageID == null) {
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed to check in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/feed", params, HttpMethod.POST, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                                    if (response.getError() == null) {
                                        //success
                                    } else {
                                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed to check in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }).executeAsync();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException q) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),q.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                q.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    }).executeAsync();
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code only checks in to locations with facebook pages via pageid. ( Like restaurants.) But think you can do it with place id too.

```
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(
                            getActivity(), Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
                    String PAGEID = FACEBOOK_LINK.substring(
                            FACEBOOK_LINK.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                            FACEBOOK_LINK.length());
                    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/"
                            + PAGEID, null, HttpMethod.GET,
                            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                    /* handle the result */

                                    try {
                                        if (response.getError() == null) {
                                            JSONObject obj = response
                                                    .getJSONObject();
                                            if (obj.has("id")) {
                                                pageID = obj.getString("id");
/* make the API call */
                                    Bundle params = new Bundle();
                                    params.putString("message", "Eating");
                                    params.putString("place", pageID);
                                    params.putString("link","URL");
                                    if (pageID == null) {
                                        MessageBox
                                                .Show(getActivity(),
                                                        "Failed to check in to this restaurant");
                                    } else {
                                        new GraphRequest(AccessToken
                                                .getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                                "/me/feed", params,
                                                HttpMethod.POST,
                                                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                                    public void onCompleted(
                                                            GraphResponse response) {

                                                        if (response.getError() == null) {
                                                            //success
                                                        } else {
                                                            MessageBox
                                                                    .Show(getActivity(),
                                                                            "Failed to check in to this restaurant");
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }).executeAsync();
                                            }
                                        } 
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        MessageBox.Show(getActivity(),
                                                "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                    }

                                }
                            }).executeAsync();
```

I know this code is a bit messy but it get the work done. Here the first thing that I am doing is asking user for facebook publish permission. Then I check if the pageID that I am checking into is valid through a graph request. If it is valid then I am checking in the user to his desired location through another request.

Comment: This code is assuming I have already logged into Facebook right? I will try this and keep you posted.

Comment: What is FACEBOOK_LINK?

Comment: That is an url of the facebook page from which I needed the pageid from. like this [link](https://www.facebook.com/pizzaguydelivery) where I only needed the "pizzaguydelivery" part to check if there was a place id for the location

Comment: Alright for now I have declared FACEBOOK_LINK as the link you have shown for now. But I am getting an error for getActivity() - Cannot resolve

Comment: Resolved it- its part of the Fragment class. Will test this code now.

Comment: oops. lets me edit the code I gave you, As I used it in a fragment so I had to use getActivity to pass the Activity context as the parameter. If you are doing this in your activity class replace getActivity with your Activity's context.

Comment: I have pasted the code I have written, is this correct?

Comment: in the params.putString("link", "URL"); give any url of a website.

Comment: What do you mean by "give any url of a website"?

Comment: So I have the code edited. Could you please let me know how do I call this fragment class from an Activity?

Comment: This is working as expected! thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can i also tag a location?

Comment: Please take a look at these.[Facbook Location](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/location/) and [Facebook Places](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/place/) and[Facebook post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/post/)